# How to find correlation between categorical data and continuous data?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, associations, categorical-data

So i have 20 different nominal categorical variables which are independent variables. Each of these variables 2-10 categories.These independent variables are string type and will be used to predict a dependent variable called price, which is a continuous variable.

What algorithm do I use to find the correlation of each variable and decide on the best variables?

Note: I have not built a machine learning model yet and am using Python.

I've tried f_oneway ANOVA from sklearn, but it does not find the correlation, instead it only compares between the group itself. I've found correlation between continuous variables for both independent and dependent variables. Help is much appreciated

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about sklearn, but perhaps this information will bring you a step closer.
First of all, when we speak about categorical data, we do not speak about correlation, we speak about association.

Generally speaking you need to use a ANOVA, chi square, or something similar to gather information on the association between a categorical variable and a continuous variable.

With ANOVA, we can calculate the inter- and intra-group variance, and then compare them. 
Look at this post, it will probably make more sense then me trying to explain:

[Click here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/893/how-to-get-correlation-between-two-categorical-variable-and-a-categorical-variab)

Comment: Is there a python solution?

Comment: Can you please use Google (or any other search engine for that matter)?

https://www.marsja.se/four-ways-to-conduct-one-way-anovas-using-python/